# Music won't play on my iPhone 5s why not?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I go onto my music and select a playlist I want to listen to, I then click shuffle or select and song and it won't play. It looks like it is about to play but then it automatically pauses and skips to the next song. If you click play it restarts the song - no sound comes out and if it switches to a song that does decide to act normally there is no sound at all. I have tried plugging in head phones; this makes no difference and then taking them out; this again makes no difference. I have tried turning on the ringer and turning it off, again this makes no difference. Mobile data on, data off, no difference. Bottom line is I can't play my music. I am using an iPhone 5s with iOS 10.2. Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried also restarting the phone? I have the same phone model and do have to reboot it every once in a while.